# Mvc4 App_Code class not visible to _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, app-code

I've made a `mvc4` project. It's a standard internet project made by `Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web`. And in there I've added a folder called `App_Code`, and inside that I made a `class` called `SessionHandler.cs`.
Then I open the pre-made file `_Layout.cshtml` found in /views/shared/_Layout.cshtml. In there I try calling the class `SessionHandler.cs` which I made, but it doesn't seem to be able to find the class.

How can I make the `SessionHandler.cs` class visible to `_Layout.cshtml`?

---

## ***EDIT:***

Just adding some more info on my project:

The structure:

[image]

The SessionHandler.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestingGround01.App_Code
{
    public class SessionHandler
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Web.config file located inside of your Views folder, place a namespace inclusion.

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="TestingGround01.App_Code">
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

To clarify, this is useful for EXTERNAL references.  In your case, if you simply stick a

```
@using TestingGround01.App_Code
```

at the top of your _layout.cshmtl file, it should resolve the reference just fine.

Then, you can instantiate your class inside your _layout.

```
@{ var s = new SessionHandler(); }
```

Comment: I guess that `RootNamespace` need to be replaced with the name of my project

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard Correct.  That's just an example.  It would be the full namespace of your SessionHandler.cs file in App_Code

Comment: so something like "SessionHandler.App_Code"?

I'm testing the code, and I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard what is the full namespace of your SessionHandler.cs file?

Comment: The namespace for SessionHandler is TestingGround01.App_Code. I've already tried with that, but still no result

Comment: Does it make a difference which web.config file I add it to. I've got two in my project

Comment: It needs to be added to the web.config file INSIDE of your views folder.  It is the one that is responsible for view namespacing inclusions

Comment: I added it in that web.config file. Under <configuration> --> <system.web> is that correct? cause that don't seem to do anything

Comment: Is the build action for the code file in your app_code folder set to compile?

Comment: @MikeCheel Yes it is ^^